# error "Cannot find module 'material-ui/src/navigation/close"

Tags: material-ui

In http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/appbar the second example is

```
<AppBar
  title={<span>Title</span>}
  iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
  iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Save" />} />
```

but when I try to import NavigationClose with

```
import NavigationClose = require('material-ui/src/navigation/close');
```

I get the error "Cannot find module 'material-ui/src/navigation/close", probably because it is not defined in

```
/// <reference path="../typings/material-ui/material-ui.d.ts" />
```

This is the only react element within this example which causes an error. And yes, the close.js file exists, properly formatted.

How do I fix this?

(Using Typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is wrong.
Try with:

```
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/close';
```

Comment: ...plus I had to create the definition itself, which was missing from the downloaded material-ui.d.ts file